# Should the [llc] tag be merged with the [limited-liability-company] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

At the time of writing, the recently created [llc](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/llc) tag has [one question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/llc), whereas the [limited-liability-company](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limited-liability-company) tag has [71 questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/limited-liability-company?tab=newest&page=2&pagesize=50) and has been with us since the beginning of 2019.

It seems sensible to merge the former as a synonym of the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes

Also, make LLC a synonym for the long form.